# really simple color picker how to import it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I'm new to JS and Node.js - I'm currenty working on a project and using node.js and successfully added a small package to my project called really simple color picker - https://www.npmjs.com/package/really-simple-colorpicker . The package is listed in the package.json file . When I try to use it as $(element).colorPicker() I become an error that the property doesnt exsist on JQuery . 
I have tried to import it as :

```
import "really-simple-colorpicker";
```

but i'm getting :

```
(1,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'really-simple-colorpicker'.
```

I have tried to create a simple dummy declaration file index.d.ts containing:

```
declare module 'really-simple-colorpicker';
```

but this also doesn't work .

How should I import it and use it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue - here is the deal :

1. I missed to mention that I'm working with typescript
2. I noticed there are no @types for this module so that is why it was unknown to the compiler
3. I have imported jquery as follows in the Class where I use the colorPicker():

   import * as $ from "jquery";

   import * as jQuery from "jquery";

I have also added the following line :

```
let colorPicker = require("really-simple-colorpicker");
```

then I made the cast as follows in my code :

```
(<any>colorBox).colorPicker();
```

then it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you have git installed on your computer, clone [this repo](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker) or download it as a zip. Otherwise, if you have npm, run "npm install really-simple-colorpicker" from the command line and there will be some nice sample code as shown below.

```js
/**
 * Really Simple Color Picker in jQuery
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2012
 * Lakshan Perera (www.laktek.com) & Daniel Lacy (daniellacy.com)
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to
 * deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the
 * rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
 * sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
 * IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

(function ($) {
    /**
     * Create a couple private variables.
    **/
    var selectorOwner,
        activePalette,
        cItterate       = 0,
        templates       = {
            control : $('<div class="colorPicker-picker">&nbsp;</div>'),
            palette : $('<div id="colorPicker_palette" class="colorPicker-palette" />'),
            swatch  : $('<div class="colorPicker-swatch">&nbsp;</div>'),
            hexLabel: $('<label for="colorPicker_hex">Hex</label>'),
            hexField: $('<input type="text" id="colorPicker_hex" />')
        },
        transparent     = "transparent",
        lastColor;

    /**
     * Create our colorPicker function
    **/
    $.fn.colorPicker = function (options) {

        return this.each(function () {
            // Setup time. Clone new elements from our templates, set some IDs, make shortcuts, jazzercise.
            var element      = $(this),
                opts         = $.extend({}, $.fn.colorPicker.defaults, options),
                defaultColor = $.fn.colorPicker.toHex(
                        (element.val().length > 0) ? element.val() : opts.pickerDefault
                    ),
                newControl   = templates.control.clone(),
                newPalette   = templates.palette.clone().attr('id', 'colorPicker_palette-' + cItterate),
                newHexLabel  = templates.hexLabel.clone(),
                newHexField  = templates.hexField.clone(),
                paletteId    = newPalette[0].id,
                swatch, controlText;


            /**
             * Build a color palette.
            **/
            $.each(opts.colors, function (i) {
                swatch = templates.swatch.clone();

                if (opts.colors[i] === transparent) {
                    swatch.addClass(transparent).text('X');
                    $.fn.colorPicker.bindPalette(newHexField, swatch, transparent);
                } else {
                    swatch.css("background-color", "#" + this);
                    $.fn.colorPicker.bindPalette(newHexField, swatch);
                }
                swatch.appendTo(newPalette);
            });


            newHexLabel.attr('for', 'colorPicker_hex-' + cItterate);

            newHexField.attr({
                'id'    : 'colorPicker_hex-' + cItterate,
                'value' : defaultColor
            });

            newHexField.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    var hexColor = $.fn.colorPicker.toHex($(this).val());
                    $.fn.colorPicker.changeColor(hexColor ? hexColor : element.val());
                }
                if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                    $.fn.colorPicker.hidePalette();
                }
            });

            newHexField.bind("keyup", function (event) {
              var hexColor = $.fn.colorPicker.toHex($(event.target).val());
              $.fn.colorPicker.previewColor(hexColor ? hexColor : element.val());
            });

            $('<div class="colorPicker_hexWrap" />').append(newHexLabel).appendTo(newPalette);

            newPalette.find('.colorPicker_hexWrap').append(newHexField);
            if (opts.showHexField === false) {
                newHexField.hide();
                newHexLabel.hide();
            }

            $("body").append(newPalette);

            newPalette.hide();


            /**
             * Build replacement interface for original color input.
            **/
            newControl.css("background-color", defaultColor);

            newControl.bind("click", function () {
                if( element.is( ':not(:disabled)' ) ) {
                                    $.fn.colorPicker.togglePalette($('#' + paletteId), $(this));
                }
            });

            if( options && options.onColorChange ) {
              newControl.data('onColorChange', options.onColorChange);
            } else {
              newControl.data('onColorChange', function() {} );
            }

            if (controlText = element.data('text'))
                newControl.html(controlText)

            element.after(newControl);

            element.bind("change", function () {
                element.next(".colorPicker-picker").css(
                    "background-color", $.fn.colorPicker.toHex($(this).val())
                );
            });

            element.val(defaultColor);

            // Hide the original input.
            if (element[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
                try {
                    element.attr('type', 'hidden')
                } catch(err) { // oldIE doesn't allow changing of input.type
                    element.css('visibility', 'hidden').css('position', 'absolute')
                }
            } else {
                element.hide();
            }

            cItterate++;
        });
    };

    /**
     * Extend colorPicker with... all our functionality.
    **/
    $.extend(true, $.fn.colorPicker, {
        /**
         * Return a Hex color, convert an RGB value and return Hex, or return false.
         *
         * Inspired by http://code.google.com/p/jquery-color-utils
        **/
        toHex : function (color) {
            // If we have a standard or shorthand Hex color, return that value.
            if (color.match(/[0-9A-F]{6}|[0-9A-F]{3}$/i)) {
                return (color.charAt(0) === "#") ? color : ("#" + color);

            // Alternatively, check for RGB color, then convert and return it as Hex.
            } else if (color.match(/^rgb\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3})\s*\)$/)) {
                var c = ([parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10), parseInt(RegExp.$2, 10), parseInt(RegExp.$3, 10)]),
                    pad = function (str) {
                        if (str.length < 2) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = 2 - str.length; i < len; i++) {
                                str = '0' + str;
                            }
                        }

                        return str;
                    };

                if (c.length === 3) {
                    var r = pad(c[0].toString(16)),
                        g = pad(c[1].toString(16)),
                        b = pad(c[2].toString(16));

                    return '#' + r + g + b;
                }

            // Otherwise we wont do anything.
            } else {
                return false;

            }
        },

        /**
         * Check whether user clicked on the selector or owner.
        **/
        checkMouse : function (event, paletteId) {
            var selector = activePalette,
                selectorParent = $(event.target).parents("#" + selector.attr('id')).length;

            if (event.target === $(selector)[0] || event.target === selectorOwner[0] || selectorParent > 0) {
                return;
            }

            $.fn.colorPicker.hidePalette();
        },

        /**
         * Hide the color palette modal.
        **/
        hidePalette : function () {
            $(document).unbind("mousedown", $.fn.colorPicker.checkMouse);

            $('.colorPicker-palette').hide();
        },

        /**
         * Show the color palette modal.
        **/
        showPalette : function (palette) {
            var hexColor = selectorOwner.prev("input").val();

            palette.css({
                top: selectorOwner.offset().top + (selectorOwner.outerHeight()),
                left: selectorOwner.offset().left
            });

            $("#color_value").val(hexColor);

            palette.show();

            $(document).bind("mousedown", $.fn.colorPicker.checkMouse);
        },

        /**
         * Toggle visibility of the colorPicker palette.
        **/
        togglePalette : function (palette, origin) {
            // selectorOwner is the clicked .colorPicker-picker.
            if (origin) {
                selectorOwner = origin;
            }

            activePalette = palette;

            if (activePalette.is(':visible')) {
                $.fn.colorPicker.hidePalette();

            } else {
                $.fn.colorPicker.showPalette(palette);

            }
        },

        /**
         * Update the input with a newly selected color.
        **/
        changeColor : function (value) {
            selectorOwner.css("background-color", value);
            selectorOwner.prev("input").val(value).change();

            $.fn.colorPicker.hidePalette();

            selectorOwner.data('onColorChange').call(selectorOwner, $(selectorOwner).prev("input").attr("id"), value);
        },


        /**
         * Preview the input with a newly selected color.
        **/
        previewColor : function (value) {
            selectorOwner.css("background-color", value);
        },

        /**
         * Bind events to the color palette swatches.
        */
        bindPalette : function (paletteInput, element, color) {
            color = color ? color : $.fn.colorPicker.toHex(element.css("background-color"));

            element.bind({
                click : function (ev) {
                    lastColor = color;

                    $.fn.colorPicker.changeColor(color);
                },
                mouseover : function (ev) {
                    lastColor = paletteInput.val();

                    $(this).css("border-color", "#598FEF");

                    paletteInput.val(color);

                    $.fn.colorPicker.previewColor(color);
                },
                mouseout : function (ev) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#000");

                    paletteInput.val(selectorOwner.css("background-color"));

                    paletteInput.val(lastColor);

                    $.fn.colorPicker.previewColor(lastColor);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /**
     * Default colorPicker options.
     *
     * These are publibly available for global modification using a setting such as:
     *
     * $.fn.colorPicker.defaults.colors = ['151337', '111111']
     *
     * They can also be applied on a per-bound element basis like so:
     *
     * $('#element1').colorPicker({pickerDefault: 'efefef', transparency: true});
     * $('#element2').colorPicker({pickerDefault: '333333', colors: ['333333', '111111']});
     *
    **/
    $.fn.colorPicker.defaults = {
        // colorPicker default selected color.
        pickerDefault : "FFFFFF",

        // Default color set.
        colors : [
            '000000', '993300', '333300', '000080', '333399', '333333', '800000', 'FF6600',
            '808000', '008000', '008080', '0000FF', '666699', '808080', 'FF0000', 'FF9900',
            '99CC00', '339966', '33CCCC', '3366FF', '800080', '999999', 'FF00FF', 'FFCC00',
            'FFFF00', '00FF00', '00FFFF', '00CCFF', '993366', 'C0C0C0', 'FF99CC', 'FFCC99',
            'FFFF99', 'CCFFFF', '99CCFF', 'FFFFFF'
        ],

        // If we want to simply add more colors to the default set, use addColors.
        addColors : [],

        // Show hex field
        showHexField: true
    };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div.colorPicker-picker {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: url(../arrow.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size:0.75em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align: center;
}

div.colorPicker-palette {
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #598FEF;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap {width: 100%; float:left }
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap label {font-size: 95%; color: #2F2F2F; margin: 5px 2px; width: 25%}
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap input {margin: 5px 2px; padding: 0; font-size: 95%; border: 1px solid #000; width: 65%; }

div.colorPicker-swatch {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Really Simple Color Picker</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //Run the code when document ready
  $(function() {    
   //use this method to add new colors to pallete
   //$.fn.colorPicker.addColors(['000', '000', 'fff', 'fff']);
   
   $('#color1').colorPicker();

   $('#color2').colorPicker();

   $('#color3').colorPicker({pickerDefault: "ffffff", colors: ["ffffff", "000000", "111FFF", "C0C0C0", "FFF000"], transparency: true}); 

    $('#color4').colorPicker();

    $('#color5').colorPicker({showHexField: false});
   
   //fires an event when the color is changed
   //$('#color1').change(function(){
    //alert("color changed");
   //});

   $("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#color1").val("#ffffff");   
    $("#color1").change();
   });

   $("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#color2").val("#000000");   
    $("#color2").change();
   });

  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
/* styles adopted from Nidahas - Forms markup and CSS (http://nidahas.com/2006/12/06/forms-markup-and-css-revisited/) */
/* General styles */
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font: 80%/1.5 Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #111; background-color: #FFF; }
h2 { margin: 0px; padding: 10px; font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size: 200%; font-weight: normal; color: #FFF; background-color: #CCC; border-bottom: #BBB 2px solid; }
p#copyright { margin: 20px 10px; font-size: 90%; color: #999; }

/* Form styles */
div.form-container { margin: 10px; padding: 5px; background-color: #FFF; }

p.legend { margin-bottom: 1em; }
p.legend em { color: #C00; font-style: normal; }

div.form-container div.controlset {display: block; float:left; width: 100%; padding: 0.25em 0;}

div.form-container div.controlset label, 
div.form-container div.controlset input,
div.form-container div.controlset div { display: inline; float: left; }

div.form-container div.controlset label { width: 200px;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/colorPicker.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

 <h2>Really Simple Color Picker (jQuery)</h2>

 <p>More information about this can be found in <a href="http://laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/" title="Really Simple Color Picker in jQuery">this blog article</a>.</p>
 <div class="form-container">
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
   <div class="controlset"><label for="color1">Color 1</label> <input id="color1" type="text" name="color1" value="#333399" /></div>
   <div class="controlset"><label for="color2">Color 2</label> <input id="color2" type="text" name="color2" value="#FF0000" /></div>
   <div class="controlset"><label for="color3">Color 3 (with custom colors)</label> <input id="color3" type="text" name="color3" value="#99cc00" /></div>
      <div class="controlset"><label for="color4">Color 4 (with text in box)</label> <input id="color4" type="text" name="color4" value="#FF0000" data-text="AG" /></div>
      <div class="controlset"><label for="color5">Color 5 (without hex field)</label> <input id="color5" type="text" name="color5" value="#FF00FF" /></div>

  </fieldset>
  
    <div class="buttonrow">
      <div><button type="button" id="button1">Set Color 1 to #FFF</button></div>
      <div><button type="button" id="button2">Set Color 2 to #000</button></div>
    </div>

 </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this was not what i have asked for. I was able to add the module to my project, but then what? How to use it in my code when the .colorPicker() property is unknown to the compiler